# return list of file in java web rest service

Tags: java

I am new in java rest web service. I am writing a web service method to return a List of file.I am using jersey. But I got the error 500. I used GenericEntity for returning the list. I am stuck from last 2 days. Here I have added the code. Please help.

```
@GET
@Path("/getAttachmentsList")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_ATOM_XML)
public Response getAttachmentList(){
    ArrayList<File> list=new ArrayList<File>();
    for(int i=1;i<=6;i++){
          File file = new File("C:/Users/name/Sample_"+i+".pdf");
          list.add(file);
      }
      GenericEntity<ArrayList<File>> genericList=new GenericEntity<ArrayList<File>>(list){};
      return Response.ok(genericList).build();

}
```

Comment: If you get a 500 (internal server error) you should look into your logfiles to see what is happend

Comment: SEVERE: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/atom+xml, type=class java.util.ArrayList, genericType=java.util.ArrayList<java.io.File>

Comment: this error is coming.I think I should change MediaType. But I don't understand which mediaType should I use

Comment: This is ambiguous : do you need to return the files' contents ? Or the file names ? I, just as the JAXRS framework, am confused. And rightly so. How should a java.io.File object appear in the response ? The framework does not know, and so it fails. If you want to do it, you need, either to register a "BodyWriter" for the java.io.FileType in the APPLICATION_ATOM_XML content-type (teach the framework how to handle files), or to use an object type that the framework already knows about as the response (e.g; List<String> instead of List<File>).

Answer (score 0):

Please check for the jar files you have added.

If you continue to use application_atom_xml, be sure to add the jersey-atom dependencies in pom.xml

Comment: I don't know which MediaType is perfect for returning a list of file. I have tried with json,multipart,xml but it is not working. Can u please suggest which mediaType is perfect for returning a List of File.